# Change address label from Zip/Postcode to Postcode/Zip in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

You would have thought this would have been a fairly straightforward task, however, I can't for the life of me, find where it is originally set. I'd like to make a few other changes once I know which file to look for. any help much appreciated.

Comment: Change the address label where? customer section , checkout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please check if you have any party extension installed.

If not then please check the below steps

You need to create one folder in your theme name i18n and create file en_US.csv en_US is the language code it depends on your language code.

you need to change the value from Zip/Postcode to Postcode/Zip .

The second method is to enable translate inline and change the word that you want to change.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html